# C++ stringstream function does not return correctly

Tags: c++, pointers, stack, stringstream

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stack>
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>

    using namespace std;

    stack<char> aStack;
    stringstream result;
    stack<char> operand1;
    stack<char> operand2;


    stringstream &postfixExp(string ch){
      for(int i =0; i< ch.length(); i++)
      {
        if(ch[i]== '1' || ch[i]== '2' || ch[i]== '3' || ch[i]== '4' || ch[i]== '5' || ch[i]== '6' || ch[i]== '7' || ch[i]== '8' || ch[i]== '9' || ch[i]== '0' )
        {
          aStack.push(ch[i]);
        }

        else if( ch[i]== '+')
        {
          operand2.push(aStack.top());
          aStack.pop();

          operand1.push(aStack.top());
          aStack.pop();

      result << ( operand1.top() + operand1.top());
    }

  }

  return result;
}

int main()
{
    string postfix = " 2+3";

    stringstream* answer = &postfixExp(postfix);
    cout << "Result = " << answer->str() << endl;;


  return 0;
}
```

Hi everyone, does anyone know what is wrong with my code ? 
I do not see any error message from the compiler. However it crashes when I run it.

I'm having a difficult time to display the result which I got from my function.
I initially wanted to use a stack function, but I couldn't think of how to pass the value to the main function and display it.

Then I'm thinking to use stringstream function instead. Unfortunately, I still don't know how to display the corresponding result

I wonder if anyone could tell me which part is wrong in my code, or if there is a better way to display the result from the function other than using stringstream or stack

Thanks a lot!

Comment: error: attempt to access an element in an empty container. http://codepad.org/Qh7tiZzK

Comment: With the string you're using to test (" 2+3"), your stack would only have one value in it when you get to the "+" operator, so you're probably running into an error when you try to pop two operands off the stack. Did you mean for your test string to be " 23+"?

Comment: Also, you answers are going to be way off because you're adding the ascii values of the characters, not the actual numbers...

Comment: "result << ( operand1.top() + operand1.top());" I assume you did not mean to add the first operand to itself.

Comment: @duDE wow, I couldn't see any error message in my pocketC++  Does it mean that my pointer 'answer' refers to nothing ? Didn't I refer it to the stringstream function correctly ?

Comment: You try to pop off two operands off the stack when there is only 1 before the +

Comment: @DariusMakaitis Oh my gosh, you're right ! It supposed to be "23+" instead. Indeed, the answer is way off because I'm adding the ascii values. Why does the '+' sign doesn't add the actual numbers ? How can I add the actual numbers ?

Comment: Since the ascii code for '0' is 48, and they go sequentially from there, the easy way to get the int value from an ascii character '0'-'9' is to subtract 48 from the ascii value. http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was pointed out already, error is caused by calling `aStack.pop();` while the `aStack` container is empty. This probably yields ***undefined behavior*** that (in this case) you are able to observe as a crash of your application.

Explanation is simple, you process string `"2+3"` character by character:

```
for each character:
    if it is digit:
        push it to stack
    if it is '+':
        pop 2 elements
```

... so what do you think will happen in `"2+3"` string once the `'+'` sign is reached?

---

Also consider redesigning this:

```
stringstream result;

stringstream& postfixExp(string ch) {
    ...
    return result;
}
```

... you're returning a reference to global variable, which means you either shouldn't return anything or the variable shouldn't be global. Yet even better, consider passing only `std::string` objects instead (use `stringstream` locally within the function):

```
std::string postfixExp(const std::string& expression) {
    std::ostringstream resultStream;
    ...
    return result.str();
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! you're very helpful. I will read more about you're suggestion about reference, but for now what's important for me is to make my program return the result of postfix notation correctly. In the meantime, I changed my code a little bit into http://codepad.org/g4DopA44 . The result of my new postfix notation "34+2*" should be 14, but it shows 'g' instead

Answer (score 0):

Test input for a postfix arithmetic operation should be in the form of "23+", not "2+3".

Some checks should probably be added to ensure you're not popping from an empty stack, as others have mentioned.